# I want to split my string with the following symbols: +, -, *, / but .split function only accepts one

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, split

Currently, this is my code:

```
public void setEquals(View v){
    EditText txtDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
    display = txtDisplay.getText().toString();
    String[] strArrDisplay = display.split("\\+");
    txtDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(strArrDisplay[0]));
```

My current code can only split successfully the plus sign(+). I want the string to be split if there is a plus, minus, multiply, or divide signs.

Let's say the input would be: 123+5-2
so the desired output should be:

```
strArrDisplay[0] = "123"
strArrDisplay[1] = "5"
strArrDisplay[2] = "2"
```

Comment: What language? Tag it. Also fix the indentation

Comment: I'm new in stackoverflow so my apologies. The programming language is Java because I'm developing an Android App.

Comment: Do you mean you want to split on any of those characters or all of them?  Please show examples of input and output.

Comment: @user3262417 - That is ok. Perhaps getting a real username will also help. But you get a +1 to get you started

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String.split takes a regex to split on, so you can simply:

```
 String[] array = myString.split("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/");
```

please give me some feedback

Hope that helps .

Comment: That splits on point and dash.  What use it that to the OP?  Did you just copy and paste this from some other question?

Comment: @Simon i wrote just  an example , and now updated my answer just like what he wants :)

Comment: OK, downvote reversed.  A neater solution might be `split(Pattern.quote("+-/*"))`

Comment: Thanks Amrola! I am new to this language and I'm not really good in String manipulation. :)

Comment: Asking for upvotes is considered bad behaviour on Stackoverflow.  The accept indicates a correct, accepted solution.  Upvotes are for answers that add something extra.  This is such a simple Q&A, what is it that makes your believe that your answer adds more value than providing a solution to the question?

Comment: sorry , i have been answering question on stackoverflow for the last 2 weeks , so i didnt know .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringTokenizer` to split your string.

```
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer("123+766-12", "-+*/");
    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        Log.d("test", tokens.nextToken());
    }
```